# Search does not work

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, enterprise-search

After adding **alias** for the server, the search stopped returning the value.

Alias added to DNS, registered alternative configuration on Intranet and Search Service Application: Server Name Mappings.

What is the problem?

Comment: You need to explain your case bit further, what is the target of crawling, what version of SP are you using (and which type of search service). Are the items in the index or crawling throws some errors during crawl.

Comment: SP 2016 Ent, need add alias name Content Source (Local SharePoint sites) http://sp and sps3://sp?

Comment: Server Alias for Local  Sharepoint Site?? this doesn't make much sense. Can you elaborate further.

Comment: What else to write the rest of the standard, the content of the resource status idle (successfully passed through the entire collection)

Comment: If you updated AAM you don't need Server Name Mapping. Did you change the Start Address? Usually this will be the problem if you are not crawling the Default Zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set AAM for your web application? If yes, you need to configure content source using the default zone url.

In addition, if you configure Server Name Mappings, remember to do a full crawl for your content source.

There are two articles for your reference:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/enterprisesearch/2010/05/28/server-name-mapping-and-alternate-access-mapping-aam/ 
[Alternate Access Mappings (AAMs) *Explained](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint_strategery/2013/05/27/alternate-access-mappings-aams-explained/)